# JavaScript menu behaving strangely in Chrome

Tags: php, html, javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I have a dropdown javascript menu on a site that gets included into each page by some php.  There's no problem in Firefox, but when viewed in Chrome, the menu acts strangely on most of the pages, but not all, and I can't figure out what's going correctly on the few proper pages.

The homepage looks fine in either one: http://solve-et-coagula.us/

Like this page, most (in Chrome) add a space above the menu: http://solve-et-coagula.us/design.php

This page displays correctly: /rabbithole/k_2.php

This one does not: /hermeticism/gunas.php

Also, in all cases in Chrome, the dropdowns appear from the top of the menu images instead of the bottom.

I've been using the menu for a while, having grabbed the format somewhere years ago and adapting it aesthetically.

The pages start off like (k_2.php):

```
<?php
session_name("MyLogin");
session_start();
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/menu.html");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
<head>
<title>Registration</title>
<meta content="text/html" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rabbithole.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/general.css" />
<script src="/javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="rabbithole.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="0" cellspacing="20" width="100%">
<tr>
<td class="title"><h1>Create an Account</h1></td>
</tr>
[...]
```

---

### Here's the graphic design page

```
<?php
session_name("MyLogin");
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
<head>
<title>Graphic & Web Design</title>
<meta content="text/html" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rabbithole/rabbithole.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="general.css" />
<script src="javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/menu.html");
?>
<table border="0" cellspacing="20" width="100%">
<tr>
<td class="title"><h1>Graphic & Web Design</h1></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<p>
[...]
```

---

### here's the full menu.html file

```
<div align="center" id="page">
<div id="header">
<div id="mainmenu">
<span onmouseover="dropdownmenu(this, event, menu1, '146px')" onclick="return clickreturnvalue()" onmouseout="delayhidemenu()"><img alt="Hermetic Qabalah" class="menuimages" src="/images/libri.png" /></span>
<span onmouseover="dropdownmenu(this, event, menu2, '146px')" onclick="return clickreturnvalue()" onmouseout="delayhidemenu()"><img alt="Eastern Mysticism" class="menuimages" src="/images/theology.png" /></span>
<span onmouseover="dropdownmenu(this, event, menu3, '146px')" onclick="return clickreturnvalue()" onmouseout="delayhidemenu()"><img alt="Ceremonial Magick" class="menuimages" src="/images/rituals.png" /></span>
<span onmouseover="dropdownmenu(this, event, menu4, '146px')" onclick="return clickreturnvalue()" onmouseout="delayhidemenu()"><img alt="Solve et Coagula" class="menuimages" src="/images/solveetcoagula.png" /></span>
<span onmouseover="dropdownmenu(this, event, menu5, '146px')" onclick="return clickreturnvalue()" onmouseout="delayhidemenu()"><img alt="Liber Legis" class="menuimages" src="/images/thelema.png" /></span>
<span onmouseover="dropdownmenu(this, event, menu6, '146px')" onclick="return clickreturnvalue()" onmouseout="delayhidemenu()"><img alt="Lemegeton" class="menuimages" src="/images/lemegeton.png" /></span>
<span onmouseover="dropdownmenu(this, event, menu7, '146px')" onclick="return clickreturnvalue()" onmouseout="delayhidemenu()"><img alt="Miscellanea" class="menuimages" src="/images/hermeticism.png" /></span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

An help would be appreciated; this has not been solved.

Comment: Firstly include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/menu.html"); Should be inside the `body` and *menu.html* should not have any `head` because the containing page will have one. And the title,meta, link tags should be in the `head`.

Comment: I'll stick that into body, but I've tried it in the past and not noticed a difference.  Also, the menu page has no head, I'll add both to the question.

Answer (score 1):

On http://solve-et-coagula.us/design.php there is extra `" "` at the top (not present on other pages), when its removed then the menu is displayed properly.

Take a look into the code of that page, and see if anything extra is being `echoed` by PHP.

[image]

Also, You should have the *meta  link and title* tag inside the `head` element.

Comment: I noticed the space and agree that's what causes the relocation, however I've found nothing causing it and can't find discrepancies between the pages that do and don't work.
Also, Meta link and title are within the head element, they get pushed out like that during runtime.